# Jaya and Vijaya:Vishnu's option

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana

After the curse to Jaya and Vijaya from Kumaras , Vishnu appeared before them, and the gatekeepers requested Vishnu to lift the curse of the Kumaras. Vishnu said that the curse of the Kumaras cannot be reversed. Instead, he gives Jaya and Vijaya two options. **The first option is to take seven births on Earth as a devotee of Vishnu, while the second is to take three births as his enemy.** After serving either of these sentences, they can re-attain their stature at Vaikuntha and be with him permanently.

My question is regarding those two options. What is actual meaning of those options why did Vishnu gave like that?

Why being enemy of lord was faster way to go to adobe of Lord? Is this case true for all souls?